# How to create an instance of byte[] with lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, arrays, lambda, reflection, expression

The code below works perfectly with a lot of objects in the "T" parameter.

```
ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
NewExpression newExpression = Expression.New(constructorInfo);
dynamic instance = Expression.Lambda<Func<dynamic>>(newExpression).Compile()();
```

But, if "T" is a **byte[]**, an exception occurs.

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: construtor at Expression.New(ConstructorInfo consctructor)
```

I would like to operate this code with a byte array parameter, while keeping it generic.

I hope you can help me solve this error.

Comment: `byte[]` doesn't have a constructor, it's an array. For example, you can't write `var x = new byte[]()`

Comment: If you have byte[] then the lambda expression needs to end with ToArray() and the type that is returned from lambda also needs to be byte[].

Comment: If its an array (i.e. `typeof(T).IsArray`) you would need to do `Expression.NewArrayBounds(typeof(T).GetElementType(), Expression.Constant(0))`. Also I don't get why your are returning `dynamic` when you know it's `T`.

Comment: Thanks @ckuri. It works perfectly ! I put my refactored code in response to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for keeping the generic object generation even with a byte array.

```
T instance;

if (!typeof(T).IsArray)
{
    ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    NewExpression newExpression = Expression.New(constructorInfo);
    instance = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(newExpression).Compile()();
}
else
{
    NewArrayExpression newArrayExpression = Expression.NewArrayBounds(typeof(T).GetElementType(), Expression.Constant(0));
    instance = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(newArrayExpression).Compile()();
}
```

Thanks for your comments guys.

Comment: Hi, you should accept your own answer do that others with the same question will see at a glance that it's already answered.

Comment: @ckuri, yes it's planned, but I must wait 2 days after asking the question.